# jQuery does not load on Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im currently trying to do some work on some code I did not write or fully understand. The page dynamically calls in content with AJAX. I am trying to manipulate that content but of course because the page has already been loaded when I apply it to the dynamic content it gets ignored. Here are some basic examples of the jQuery i'm trying to call:

```
$(".check").each(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    var $image = $("<img src='img/checked.png' />").insertAfter(this);
    $image.click(function() {
        var $checkbox = $(this).prev(".check");
        $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));

        if ($checkbox.prop("checked")) {
            $image.attr("src", "img/checked.png");
        } else {
            $image.attr("src", "img/unchecked.png");
        }
    })
});

if ($(window).width() < 500) {
    $('.panel-collapse').removeClass('in');
} else {
    $('.panel-collapse').addClass('in');
}
```

How can I get this to work with ajax please?

Comment: Your posted code is part of content loaded through ajax or is part of main page? What about posting your code/logic regarding how do you load content using ajax?!

Comment: Its loaded on the main page, you can see the code in full here: view-source:http://ifyouneedafriendgetadog.com/jobs/ (dev url)

Comment: Delegate events for dynamic elements. Now because your code not just only bind events, you should set it in a function and call it (again?) once your ajax has finish. There are thousand already dupes regarding this, if i'm correct... FYI, this is quite inconsistent to check for `$(window).width()`, use instead: [window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I will give that a try

Comment: That seems to have resolved it thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use it in this way.

```
$image.on('click',function() {
        // your script 
})
```

As you adding content dynamically it need event [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

UPDATE :

```
 $("some_parent_id_or_class").on('click','img_with_some_class_or_id',function(){

    //your script
 })
```

e.g.

```
 $("some_parent_id_or_class").on('click','img',function(){

    //your script
 })
```

Comment: But `img` isn't child of `.check`, it is inserted after. If you want to be sure delegation would work (if event bubbles to that level), delegate it to `document` level

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks.Its my mistake.But i think rather than document immediate parent is much better

Comment: Ok, i give you credit for this answer even it is really complete, if OP set it in a loop as in his posted code, you will bound delegate event at each iteration of this loop. But at least, you gave the correct way to delegate event :)

Comment: @A.Wolff     :) yes there is loop